# Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

I have a vast deal of knowledge with Microsoft SQL Server and IBM DB2 databases but have little to now knowledge of Oracle. Can someone tell me what this means Oracle 10gR2/Teradata 13 as well as provide a good reference to learn about oracle databases. Primarily querying Oracle databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10gR2 is the second release (R2) of Oracle RDBMS version 10g (while current version is 12c), while [Teradata](http://www.teradata.com/) (here [13](http://www.teradata.com/article.aspx?id=13851) stands too for DB version number) is another DB vendor.

As of Oracle SQL syntax, the best resource [is documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm). [Same in pdf](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200.pdf).